# Ruby - Method to tell whether it is O's or X's turn

Tags: ruby

Would like to create a method where each time it is ran the return value is the amount of times the method has been called. Here's a quick version of what I think, I wanted it to be simple but is seemingly getting more complex the more I realize that it doesnt store the information in itself

```
def count()
  count = 0
    if count.odd?
      return "X"
    else count.even?
      return "O"
    count = count+1
  end
end
```

Comment: Don't forget that when writing code, especially when learning, indentation is *super important*. This code is a bit of a mess and the structure here is misleading.

Comment: Think about when the count = count + 1 is executed... ...

Comment: With these lines you have created a method `count` (which does not return a count)  _and_ a local variable, also `count`. While Ruby might be able to deal with this, it will confuse readers of your code, including yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Methods like this have local variables in them that go away when they "fall out of scope", or in other words, when the method finishes. If you want to persist this data you need to use an instance variable within the context of a class, for example:

```
class Counter
  def initialize
    @count = 0
  end

  def count
    @count += 1

    @count.odd? ? 'O' : 'X'
  end
end
```

That class can be *instantiated* which creates an *instance* and in this instance you can keep local data for as long as necessary by defining variables such as `@count`.

Then you can use it like this:

```
counter = Counter.new
counter.count
# => 'O'
counter.count
# => 'X'
counter.count
# => 'O'
```

Comment: Awesome I really appreciate the help! I have a rough understanding of what you did there so going to look up some of the stuff I dont know like class.

Comment: There's a good [Ruby introduction book](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/) which is available in online form as well as print. The printed version is more current, but the old online one is still pretty good and should show you through the basics.

Answer (score 1):

You have made the assumption that, for `count` to alternately return `'X'` and `'O'`, it is necessary to keep a count of the number of times `count` has been called. That is not the case, however, as illustrated by the following version of `count`.

```
def count
  @enum ||= ['X', 'O'].cycle
  @enum.next
end

count #=> "X"
count #=> "O"
count #=> "X"
count #=> "O"
```

When Ruby sees the "shorthand" expression `@enum ||= ['X', 'O'].cycle`, the first thing she does is expand it to

```
@enum = @enum || ['X', 'O'].cycle
```

When `count` is initially called, `@enum #=> nil`. We therefore obtain

```
@enum ||= ['X', 'O'].cycle
  #=>       = nil || #<Enumerator: ["X", "O"]:cycle>
  #         = #<Enumerator: ["X", "O"]:cycle>
```

In subsequent calls to `count`

```
@enum ||= ['X', 'O'].cycle
  #=> @enum = @enum || ['X', 'O'].cycle
  #         = #<Enumerator: ["X", "O"]:cycle> || #<Enumerator: ["X", "O"]:cycle>
  #         = #<Enumerator: ["X", "O"]:cycle>
```

That is, `@enum` is not changed. (`#<Enumerator: ["X", "O"]:cycle>` following `||` is not even evaluated.)

We then have

```
@enum.next #=> "X"
@enum.next #=> "O"
@enum.next #=> "X"
@enum.next #=> "O"
```

See the docs for [Array.cycle](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-cycle) and [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-next).

Comment: I like this a lot better

Comment: Btw what is the @ symbol represent? I've tried to look it up but can't find it

Comment: `@enum` is an instance variable, `enum` would be a local variable, `$enum` would be a global variable. You need an instance (or global) variable so that it's value will persist from one method call to the next.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for taking the time to help me